# How to use the OldStandard fonts with plain TeX?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex

The CTAN `fonts/oldstandard` repository contains files for the OldStandard (OS) fonts but are intended to be used with LaTeX.
How could I define `\tenrm`, `\tenbf`, `\tenit` and same with other font sizes for OS in plain TeX?

For example if I wanted to use CM I would define

```
\font\ninerm=cmr9                                                               
\font\eightrm=cmr8                                                              
\font\sixrm=cmr6
```

as Knuth did in the `taocpmac.tex` file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

with latex

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{OldStandard}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\show\the\font

\textbf{\expandafter\show\the\font}

\textit{\expandafter\show\the\font}

\large

\expandafter\show\the\font

\textbf{\expandafter\show\the\font}

\textit{\expandafter\show\the\font}
\end{document}
```

shows the fonts used:

eg the first is

```
> \OT1/OldStandard-TLF/m/n/10=select font OldStandard-Regular-tlf-ot1.
```

so you can set up the same fonts in plain

```
\font\rm=OldStandard-Regular-tlf-ot1
\font\bf=OldStandard-Bold-tlf-ot1
\font\it=OldStandard-Italic-tlf-ot1

\font\largerm=OldStandard-Regular-tlf-ot1 at 12pt
\font\largebf=OldStandard-Bold-tlf-ot1 at 12pt
\font\largeit=OldStandard-Italic-tlf-ot1 at 12pt

\tracingall
\rm Abcdef {\bf Abcdef} {\it Abcdef}

{\baselineskip=14pt
\largerm Abcdef {\largebf Abcdef} {\largeit Abcdef}

}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if I understand correctly, OS only comes in one font size and you have to magnify it in order to access 12pt?